# C# Generic return type must be non-nullable to match overridden member, even though overridden member is nullable

Tags: c#, generics, abstract, nullable

You can see the error here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/U8erNX

Basically, I make a generic abstract class. When I implement the class, I am not allowed to use nullable, even though I use it in my abstract class...

```
public abstract class A<T>
{
    public abstract T? Test();
}
    
public class B : A<int>
{
    public override int? Test() => 1; // ? is not allowed here with error: Return type must be 'int' to match overridden member
}
```

Any way to do this, or not possible?

Comment: You just missed `public abstract class B : A<int --> ? <-- >`. That's all. But ... in fact T can't be nullable ... because of `where T : notnull` ... I don't know what is notnull since I'm still in C # 7.3 in case it's something new afterwards. Thus perhaps `Test() => (Nullable<int>)1;` or `Test() => (int?)1;`. But frankly, I found all the code provided unclean and smelly.

Comment: 1 is not a nullable int...

Comment: This would not help, T nullability in general is not related to nullability of specific method return type. I have many methods which return non-null T, just like abstract method would be non-null T. (The notnull constraint also can be disregarded, it doesn't affect the error).

Comment: If it's not relevant, remove it from the [mre].

Comment: `int` and `int?` are different types. But if you use `class B : A<int?>`, then the error goes away. Using the constraint `where T : struct` also solves the problem because then `T?` will mean `Nullable<T>`, which makes `A<int>` valid.

Comment: As T just represents any type, and as @OlivierRogier mentioned, the nullability express a different type (int and int? are different types) You can't express that nullability (option in F#) in the generyc definition `T?`

Comment: `where T : struct` works, but lose some generality if I wanted to use non-structs. But this means nullable doesn't generalize well over structs/non-structs?

Answer (score 1):

So what I conclude is that the error message is a bit vague, since `Nullable` types are different for struct/non-struct, this could have been explained better. By using `where T : struct` my problem is solved, (but my abstract class is now less general). Thanks to György Kőszeg.